# Is my question on Gaming.SE not counted as a question in my SE profile because it was put on hold?

Tags: bug, profile-page

I asked a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223696/what-factors-contributed-to-e-ts-reputation-as-a-bad-game) on Arqade, which was put on hold pending meta discussion. The community decided overwhelmingly to reopen the question, but it does not appear to be included in the question count on my SE network profile. It is my only question on Arqade, but the "Accounts" tab for my profile reads "0" questions. Shouldn't it count if it's reopened?

Comment: Can we see the link?

Comment: It reads as "1" question for me. I can't repro this. CACHING!

Comment: @PythonMaster Question link is in the question, and here's the profile link: http://stackexchange.com/users/225392/sss4r?tab=accounts

Comment: FWIW, I cleared my local cache, made no difference, of course. Where is this caching taking place? On the SE servers? Interesting that we can see different results on the same page, I didn't realize that was a thing.

Comment: The SE servers. Took them 3 months to get my rep right in Area 51... :(

Comment: BTW, I haven't a clue which of the two answers should be accepted--they say the same thing basically. I suppose I could accept the one that was posted first? I think that was @nicael

Comment: Never mind, if I read it correctly, the answer is caching, and @PythonMaster went there first. Thanks to you both, I'm just trying to be fair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemingly, caching is taking a long time to catch up with the present. You should check that later and see whether it has updated or not. I know how long it could take since that happened to me... Took 3 months to finish caching. Just be patient and it should be there soon.

Oh, questions will always show up on your account if it is not deleted. If it is closed, put on hold, or open it should still be there.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that it's closed or not, locked/ not locked, etc doesn't count. The questions *do* count, unless deleted. Your question should have been shown even if it stayed closed.

So, you've just found a bug (wait 6 to 8 weeks though, maybe you should blame caching) :)

Comment: Are you kidding me? *Maybe* we should blame caching?!

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani lol :D

Comment: Hey, that was my idea!! The one about caching

Comment: @Python Yeah, I added about caching :) Cheating, you mean? But you added the paragraph similar to my first one :D

Comment: I guess we are even then